# How to set different bar width in the same series Highchart

Tags: highcharts

In my bar chart the point range is not equally, so I want to draw different widths for bar chart using highchart. However, all the solution is to draw different series. I wonder is there any solution to hack the code and only change the pointwidth inside one series?

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qCJx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to change `width` property of a column SVG element.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6o7290uf/